# LWC lighnting-input date and picklist displays different in mobile size

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm facing an issue with an LWC component that is intended for display in the Salesforce Mobile App.

We've followed the recommended approach by using the standard input type as advised in the official Salesforce documentation. However, we are encountering style issues as shown in screenshot (See field purchase order date). Inline is screenshot of UI view of the fields

[image] Per [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation) :

> "On mobile devices, this component uses the native date picker, which
> ignores the date-style attribute. The native date picker uses the
> user’s device settings for names of months and weekdays, the input
> date format, and the calendar type."

Here is the sample code snippet:

```
<lightning-input
          label="sample label"
          data-id="id"
          data-obj="order"
          type="date"
          value={}
          max={maxDate}
          onchange={handleChange}
          required
        ></lightning-input>
```

I would appreciate your assistance in clarifying whether this behavior aligns with the designed functionality or if it's a potential  bug

Any ideas on a workaround to overcome this behavior would be helpful